# Ubuntu failed to detect MegaRaid lsi

Tags: ubuntu, raid

Ubuntu(12.04) doesn't see HDS connected to MegaRaid.
I have tried upgrading the framework, installed the driver, verified it was installed, rebooted the system and still don't see the drives connected to the card.

card module:
MegaRAID SAS 9271-4i Sgl

- tried Centos 6. the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSI offers binary Linux drivers on [their support page](http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/megaraid-sas-9271-4i.aspx#tab/tab3).

However, Linux supports 3ware family (which is now also owned by LSI) much better than Megaraid. If I were you, I would return this card and get [3ware 9750-4i](http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/3ware-sas-9750-4i.aspx) instead (costs $100 less), or save some good money and buy used 3ware 9650SE-4LPML off Ebay for about $100 total.